# Join attribute table

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins, fields-attributes

I am using QGIS 1.7.3 on  Mac and when I try to use the tool "join" in the properties toolbox, I have no possibility to add a name for either the file or the field used to join tables.

Has anyone encountered this problem and solved it ???

Answer (score 4):

You will need to first load both of the layers you want to join into the map canvas - there is no option to add an *additional* file once you've opened the Properties dialog. Or am I misunderstanding the problem?

You can add any OGR compatible layer - e.g. a CSV file - as a layer (doesn't need to be a delimited text layer with X and Y!) and then do a join. The layer names and field should show up for all loaded layers.

(OSX 10.7 / QGIS 1.7.4)